# Is there a way to force certain application to be always on bottom?

Tags: windows, windows-10, always-on-top

Well, the question speaks for itself. I'm on Windows 10. Can I somehow force certain application to be always behind all other windows (as opposite to always-on-top funcion)? Thanks.

Comment: I'm curious about your use case but [what if two programs did this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413). If you own the application, you should make it a service. If you don't own the application, you could submit a request to the vendor to implement it as a service. Everything else would be kind of a hack and wil fail you sooner or later.

Comment: @Lieven_Keersmaekers.. I don't understand "make it a service".  The app he has contains a window (thus the question) and services can't have or interact with a window since Windows Vista (removal of the SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS flag).  They simply aren't allowed to interact with the desktop.  Perhaps you mean some other kind of "windows service" that I am unaware of or do you mean to ditch the window?  You have peaked my interest.  Please clarify.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - Services *can* have a window all right but no one would see it (unless you connect to the service session) so yes, I am suggesting to ditch the window. What's the point of the window if you want it behind every other window? The user will not see it most of the time.